# Using inherited constructors with a proxy factory

Tags: openzeppelin, proxy-contracts, constructor, factory, chainlink-vrf

I am attempting to use Chainlink VRF along with OpenZeppelin's upgradable contracts to generate a random number. In order to use VRF, I must inherit the constructor from VRFV2WrapperConsumerBase. However, constructors cannot be used with upgradable contracts. While my Chainlink VRF code functions properly without proxies, I get an "execution reverted" error whenever I try to make a call which requires VRF, so I guess it must be an issue with VRFV2WrapperConsumerBase and how I implemented it.

Current code:

```
contract VRFv2DirectFundingConsumer is VRFV2WrapperConsumerBase, Initializable {
    ...

    address public constant linkAddress = 0x779877A7B0D9E8603169DdbD7836e478b4624789;
    address public constant linkWrapper = 0xab18414CD93297B0d12ac29E63Ca20f515b3DB46;

    // Not allowed to inherit a constructor when using proxies
    constructor() VRFV2WrapperConsumerBase(linkAddress, linkWrapper) {
        _disableInitializers();
    }

    function initialize() public payable initializer { 
        admin = msg.sender;
    }

    // Call example
    function requestRandomWords() internal returns (uint256 requestId) {
        requestId = requestRandomness(
            callbackGasLimit,
            requestConfirmations,
            numWords
        );

        return requestId;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
contract Contract is
    Storage,
    ReentrancyGuard,
    UsingDiamondOwner,
    UserManager,
    AutomationCompatibleInterface,
    VRFConsumerBaseV2(0x8103B0A8A00be2DDC778e6e7eaa21791Cd364625) //passing values when it is inherit
{
  //contract logic
}
```

I tried like this and it worked !